# How use RingtoneManager.setType() in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, ringtonemanager

Using `Androidapi.JNI.Media` with Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

I am trying to list the available ringtones and play a different one from current default.

Initialization of `JAudioManager` and `JRingtoneManager` seems ok, because I can play the default ringtone.

But when I try to use the `RingtoneManager` to set `Type`, or get a `Cursor`, the program terminates with a system popup which say "The Application (name) was interrupted - restart the app".

```
procedure TAudioPlayBackForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AudioObj: JObject;
  AudioMgr: JAudioManager;
  RingtoneMgr: JRingtoneManager; 
  aUri: Jnet_Uri;
  cur: JCursor;
  ringt: JRingtone;
begin
  AudioObj := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.AUDIO_SERVICE );
  RingtoneMgr := TJRingtoneManager.Wrap((AudioObj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
  Log.d('TJRingtoneManager wrap ok');

  aUri := TJRingtoneManager.JavaClass.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(SharedActivityContext, TJRingtoneManager.JavaClass.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
  Log.d('getActualDefaultRingtoneUri = '+ JStringToString(aUri.toString) );                                                        

  ringt := TJRingtoneManager.JavaClass.getRingtone(SharedActivityContext, aUri);
  Log.d('getRingtone uri ok = '+ JStringToString( ringt.getTitle(SharedActivityContext) ));

  ringt.play;  // OK !

  RingtoneMgr.setType( 4 );   // <-- CRASH !
  Log.d('RingtoneMgr setType ok');

  cur := RingtoneMgr.getCursor;   // <-- CRASH !
  Log.d('RingtoneMgr getCursor ok = '+ intToStr(cur.getColumnCount));
end;
```

Any idea? Did I forget to initialize something?

I used [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager#setType(int)) as reference.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating the RingtoneManager instance incorrectly. It should be:

```
// Forget about obtaining AudioObj - it's not relevant
RingtoneMgr := TJRingtoneManager.JavaClass.init(TAndroidHelper.Activity);
```

This requires the Androidapi.Helpers unit

Comment: Incidentally, saying that the program has a "crash" isn't terribly useful. Be more specific about what happens, i.e. the *exact* error message(s) if any, and preferably provide a callstack

Comment: Thank you very much Dave. Is it necessary to free in some way the RingtoneMgr so initialized ?  I ask because after some button clicks (14) no more sound is emitted, but the App still run and produce logcat messages...

Comment: Do those logcat messages indicate any problems? Since RingtoneMgr is a local reference, and an interface, the reference will automatically be destroyed once the method exits. Same for the others

Comment: @DaveNottage since the `Activity` is passed to the "constructor" (`init()`), it might be holding a reference to the object. So you might need to explicitly `DisposeOf()` it when you are done using it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think you mean set the reference to nil.

Comment: @DaveNottage No, I meant `DisposeOf()` at the time, but I see now where your confusion is, since interfaces don't have `DisposeOf()`, only objects do.  Setting the local reference to `nil` wouldn't clear the reference being held inside of the `Activity` (if such a reference exists, I don't know), in which case, I don't know how to clear that.  If there isn't one, then this becomes a non-issue. Maybe the "no more sounds" issue is related to the `Ringtone` itself instead? Or maybe Android just gives up playing ringtones after awhile?

Comment: I solved my problem using a single global instance of RingtoneManager and then change ringtone via Cursor. This way I can play infinite times all melodies (ringtones) available in my Android device.